# why I dont get user id from mongodb if I want to change password if user is singup /login?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt

Here I have defined the routes mentioned below:-

```
import UserController from "../controllers/userController.js";
import checkUserAuth from "../middlewares/auth-middleware.js";
// route level middleware
router.use("/changepassword", checkUserAuth);
router.post("/changepassword", UserController.changePassword);
```

In this system, if the user has a valid token after login then they can change their password.

```
  let token;
  const { authorization } = req.headers;
  if (authorization && authorization.startsWith("Bearer")) {
    try {
      token = authorization.split(" ")[1];
      //   verify user token
      console.log(authorization);
      console.log(token); 
      const { userId } = Jwt.verify(token, "5DFE4FG0125DRHcgng");

      // get user from token
      req.user = await UserModel.findById("62fc541298faae7fa6db9035").select(
        "-password"
      );
      console.log(req.user);
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.send({ status: "failed", message: "unauthorized user" });
    }
  }
```

Here I have debugged that I can see the value of the token in console.log() and the token value is available here. but nothing was found in const{userid} that I can get user details and proceed for a password reset. All data is fetching, Whenever I passed userid like this

```
req.user = await UserModel.findById("62fc541298faae7fa6db9035").select("-password");
```

instead of

```
req.user = await UserModel.findById(userid).select("-password");
```

Here is the mongoose Schema.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
// Define Schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
  email: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
  password: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
  tc: { type: "String", required: true },
});
// Model
const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
export default UserModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to cast to ObjectId if your schema has it.
Please share your schema.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
req.user = await UserModel.findById(new ObjectId("62fc541298faae7fa6db9035")).select("-password");
```

**EDIT1**

This code is working.

```
//defining schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
    email: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
    password: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
    tc: { type: "String", required: true },
});
// Model
const UserModel = mongoose.model("testuser", userSchema);


(async () => {
    //CLEAR Collection!
    const user = await UserModel.create({
        "name": "Max Mustermann",
        "email": "max.mustermann@gmail.de",
        "password": "$2a$10$Ovywsn4SDhBejIQ8BEWQSepfxE0CmGZ8TYa6k/LaCmkYd3bPVGyqe",
        "tc": "unknown"
      })

    const querySameUser = await UserModel.findById(user._id).select("-password");
    console.log(querySameUser);
})();
```

and it is also working with fixed string of id.

```
//defining schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
    email: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
    password: { type: "String", required: true, trim: true },
    tc: { type: "String", required: true },
});
// Model
const UserModel = mongoose.model("testuser", userSchema);

(async () => {
    const querySameUser = await UserModel.findById("62fe43de9e960798b93bf9d4").select("-password");
    console.log(querySameUser);
})();
```

Comment: I have posted the schema.

Comment: yes, It is working but I want the user id with Jwt auth.
```req.user = await UserModel.findById(userId).select("-password");```

Comment: Ah now I got what you are talking about. Can you post your token please so to check if userId is there? You log your token in console.

Comment: I have used MongoDB compass to store my data, so will my token work for you?

Comment: I asked for your Bearer token you want to verify.